# How to enable telnet and ssh packages using yocto

Tags: ssh, embedded-linux, yocto, telnet

I am using yocto build system. I need telnet and ssh for my custom board. Can you help how I can enable telnet and ssh in yocto build system.

Comment: Adding `ssh-server-dropbear` to IMAGE_FEATURES should enable ssh (if your image inherits the core-image class). `inetutils` package contains a telnet server (telnetd). After adding it to IMAGE_INSTALL recipe, it will be available in your image.

Comment: I have added IMAGE_FEATURES_append for ssh-server-dropbear and IMAGE_INSTALL_append for ssh-server-dropbear and inetutils, but the build is failing with `"ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-minimal'` has no buildable providers.". How to check the providers.

Comment: You shouldn't add `ssh-server-dropbear` to `IMAGE_INSTALL`. It belongs only to `IMAGE_FEATURES`.

Comment: After adding `ssh-server-dropbear` to `IMAGE_INSTALL` built successfully.